# Setting Mac App Store country to home country when abroad

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore

I'm stuck trying to use the Mac App Store on my Mac. I'm in Germany (abroad, my home country is UK) and it seems my Mac has picked this up in some way and won't let me download Xcode, as it says I can't download from the German App Store. My App Store was set up in the UK with UK card details.

My Mac was initialised in Germany too, i.e. it was switched on for the first time here.

My locale settings from System Preferences are here:

[image: System Preferences show UK settings]

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Please note the following:

- I am using a MacBook Pro, not an iPad or iPhone.
- I am trying to access Mac App Store, not iTunes.

Comment: Can you go to Mac App Store, click on your name at the bottom left, then click on View Information towards top right? It will reveal your Apple ID account summary and you should be able to verify the Country/Region setting. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDCGj.png

Comment: Try to logout and log into Mac App Store using Store menu in the Mac App Store app.

Comment: OK, I did that and got a promising prompt saying I'd be switched to the UK store and it looks like it's downloading. Really poor design here from Apple. Not as bad as the mouse, but getting there!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you somehow got switched to German App Store. Your App Store home country is linked in your Apple ID and not by the system configuration. Try logging out of Mac App Store and logging back in using the Store menu in Mac App Store app.

Comment: It sounds like he/she didn't fully set up the Mac App Store before leaving for Germany.

Comment: If you read my question you'll see that I set the Mac up in Germany. It wasn't viable to travel back to the UK to set it up, so I just did it and expected the AppStore to work for downloading any globally available software.

Comment: @ToniLeigh Did you check what country is set up in Apple ID as I mentioned in [my comment] on the question? Your Apple ID account could be linked to App Store of a single country at a time, and you can download apps only available in that country's App Store (both for iOS and macOS).

Comment: @NimeshNeema yes, it's region is set to UK, it prompted me to change store when I  opened up the account info section

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a VPN connection hosted in your home country.

When I was in China (which is admittedly a different situation), I could only get to the US Mac App Store by connecting through my corporate VPN. Of course, China's country-wide Great Firewall makes things difficult.

You should have set up the App Store and all your Apple services while you were still in the UK. For now, get yourself a VPN connection back to the UK or your Mac is going to be inextricably tied to Germany.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a great option:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Bypass the AppStore completely!

Note this link will only help developers, though it's likely other apps will be downloadable outside of the app store.

Comment: There are various ways to install Mac apps apart from the Mac App Store. However, using Mac App Store is beneficial as you will get notified of the app updates and downloads will be incremental. With direct download from Apple Developer Download homepage, you'll need to download the full installer for every new release of Xcode.

Comment: @NimeshNeema fair comment, though this will get me out of a corner if the AppStore continues to be tedious. It's now doing something and has not complained of a region problem, so I suspect it's downloading.